# What is the "endgame" of Rick's group in the Walking Dead?

Tags: the-walking-dead

They obviously lived awhile in the prison but is there an overall plan, such as finding an ultimately safe haven to live? Rejoining other members of society? Finding an island or something to isolate themselves and wait out the zombies if possible? I have not heard of any ultimate plan for a permanent new way of life. Surely they want something permanent without having to deal with walkers at all.

Comment: Hey Gelfamat! Your question is good, but there is no need to end every question with "Well, lemme know" :) (just as you should avoid signing your name, or saying "thanks", or similar things)

Comment: Is it bad if I do though? It's something that has become a valuable part of my online persona. If it's bad form I'll stop...and of course, lemme know.

Comment: Not bad or good, just the etiquette here. When in Rome... :)

Comment: Their only endgame is death.  Zombies: The only winning move is not to play.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no "ideal" plan in sight. The TV series is nowhere near caught up with the comic, and nothing has been anywhere near an endgame there either.

I would go into more detail, but that would only be spoilers. They are panicked, hungry, scared and sometimes irrational. There is no endgame at this point in the TV series or the comic. There are merely reposes that the group hopes may be an endgame.

As creator Robert Kirkman said in the comic, it's not the zombies who are "The Walking
 Dead."

Comment: Interesting. It seems like their time at the prison would have allowed them some respite and they could have thought ahead about such things. Then again if it became a zombieless version of Woodberry, no one would watch.

Comment: They've nary had any respite. There is no getting comfortable. Between the Governor and the walkers and any OTHER threats, there is not enough time to do anything but concentrate on the more immediate problems like pregnancies, birth, wounds, starvation, guarding the place, supplies (medical, etc). Woodbury was only one problem.

Answer (score 3):

The latest episode (S04E09 "After") seems to be a rumination on just this very question.

Following the aftermath of the Governer's abortive retaliation on the Prison, the episode follows both Michonne and Rick/Carl respectively, and has been referred to as Walking Dead back in '[Survival Mode'](http://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/tvandradioblog/2014/feb/11/walking-dead-season-four-zombie).

The survivors wander aimlessly, attempting to find somewhere to recuperate and possibly re-unite, but without any plan/strategy other than staying alive.

The end of the Episode features a sequence in which Rick explains that he never had much hope for their 'prison of solace' plan to work out, and he believes the life they once had (domesticity, security and abundance) can never be salvaged:

> I know we'll never get things back to the way things used to be [...] I only clung to that for you. For Judith.

It seems the whole point in the walking dead is a representation of what Survival would be like **without that very endgame** that you discuss: Whether people try to create safe havens, travel nomadically, attempt to rebuild part of their lives or lose hope entirely.

It seems at this point Rick believes that the notion of finding somewhere to grow crops, create safety and live out the rest of their days in peace is a hopeless one, particularily when day to day survival is hard enough to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when there are flesh eating monsters chasing you, the first thing on your mind would be to protect yourself against them rather than rebuilding society and repopulating the earth.

That's why the protagonists of the show (and the comic) at first try to find a normal place to hide from the zombies and end up at the prison that seemed to be okay.

When they found the prison and set down, Rick suggested getting Hershel so that they can harvest the earth. That was a plan that would help them in the future, and did up to a point.