# Was Carl sexually violated?

Tags: tv, the-walking-dead

It is unclear the way the scene is shot whether or not Carl was violated sexually by the thug who was holding him to the ground, or if he was saved from it. (After Daryl's group found Rick and began to exact revenge). I doubt it, but it would explain Rick's over the top anger and vicious killing of the perpetrator.

Comment: The bigger question is why he didnt pull his gun when he was still in the car?

Comment: I would think that even the **attempted** rape of his son would explain the "over the top" anger.

Answer (score 13):

No, Carl was not raped. Not on the show or in the comic book.

From [Zap 2 It](http://blog.zap2it.com/frominsidethebox/2014/03/the-walking-dead-eps-explain-why-they-included-carls-season-4-finale-rape-scene.html) article about the TV episode:

> "That scene has always been a really difficult one," Kirkman tells TVLine. "When I was writing the original comics, in the panel description for artist Charlie Adlard I [wrote], 'Carl is on his back, and the guy is pulling his paints off -- but don't worry Charlie, *he's not going to get raped!*' I actually included that in the panel description because it is such a heavy and dark scene, and I didn't want Charlie to be freaking out while he was trying to draw that.

From Issue 58 of The Walking Dead, in the **previously** box (the attempted rape was issue 57)

> After a man *tried to rape* Carl, Rick brutally murdered him in front of Carl's eyes.

(Italics mine for emphasis.)

The site ComicBook.com has a comparison of the comic and show for the scene [here](http://comicbook.com/blog/2014/03/31/the-walking-deads-most-shocking-scene-comics-to-screen-comparison/).

Comment: Comic book is irrelevant, many things happened in the comic that never happened in the show. Question was about the tv show. If you don't think he was raped, please explain why. Just making an assertion is not helpful.

Comment: @Gelfamat: If the television programme was unclear, it is perfectly acceptable to go back to the comics. Going to outside source material is how 90% of the questions on this site get answered. There's also the not-unimportant factor that *The Walking Dead* television series is based on the comic books, so when a scene is filmed **in exactly the same manner as in the comics**, it's a safe bet that the explanation of one is also the explanation of the other.

Comment: @Gelfamat If you read my answer you'd see the first section I said "about the TV episode" was about the TV episode. And if you clicked the link I provided you'd see further quotes like "Expect to see Carl and Rick deal with the aftermath of **Carl nearly being raped** in Season 5, even if the group currently has bigger problems to deal with -- like being trapped in Terminus by maybe-cannibals."

Comment: A sexual violation does not necessarily imply an actual rape/penetration. He could have been violated without being raped. Furthermore, the comic book universe is so different than the tv show it's not even close to a valid comparison.

Comment: The "thug" was on top of Carl and turned him over (face down). The Leader said they were going to "have" the boy. You already saw that level of violation. If you aren't asking about actual rape/penetration, *what are you asking?* And the comic and TV comparison is very valid in this instance as you can see from the ComicBook.com link I posted that shows how they tried to copy most of the scene **directly from the comic.**

Comment: Are you implying he's not a thug? Lol why the quotation marks? Anyway, there are other types of violation such as with hands, objects, etc. Do you seriously not understand this?

Comment: The quotation marks were because I was **quoting.** *You* called him a "thug." And I do understand levels of violation, but you are very unclear as to what exactly you are asking. The THUG didn't have any objects, nor was he seen with his hands down Carl's pants. He was going to anal-rape Carl but was prevented from doing so. I can't get much more clear than that. I'm not sure why you are acting so confrontational. You were much more easygoing on [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/what-is-the-endgame-of-ricks-group-in-the-walking-dead) I answered.

Comment: I apologize. I am an autistic as everyone knows.